# MySQL: UPDATE database with JQuery sortable new value

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui-sortable

**I've got this:**

```
foreach($_POST['pos'] as $value) {
   $new_value = "UPDATE users SET regnr='" . $value . "' 
   WHERE username='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username']) . "'";
}

// Connect to database
$opendb = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Kunde inte ansluta till MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Kunde inte ansluta till databasen:<br>" . mysql_error());

mysql_query($new_value) or die(mysql_error());  

// Close database
mysql_close($opendb);
```

**Information:**

`$_POST['pos']` holds a value from the database in a hidden input. This value I have choosen to split with `str_split($r['regnr'], 6);` into a JQuery sortable list. If I type `echo $value;` in the foreach loop I've got the new value (not splitted, as I want) from the JQuery sortable list. I need all values from the list, and I get it with `echo`. But if I use `$value` variable to UPDATE the database that it came from, it just updates with the last value from the JQuery sortable list.

Can someone solve that? :D

Comment: Nice [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com). This code allows any malicious user to change anything they want in the users table, including making themselves superusers/admins.

Comment: How? This code is just an example this far. Haven't been focused on secure it yet.

Comment: If the user changes the value of the cookie `username`, then a user could inject this value `you-got-hacked'; DROP DATABASE;` and *poof* no more database. Yes that's how serious SQL injection can get.
Use [the PDO library](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [the MySQLi library](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: @Treps you don't add security later. You design something proper from the beginning.

Comment: Okay, I will look into that. But is there someone who can solve the actual question? :)

Comment: There is no database code, so if you do this nothing happens? If you put your database code AFTER this foreach, the string `$new_value` will only contain the UPDATE for the last value, as you overwrite it in every run. Please add more of your code so we can see what is happening?

Comment: Then mysql_real_escape_string() is an option to reject SQL-injection?

Comment: @Nanne: It will just insert the last value from the JQuery sortable list. Same result if I use all of the database code in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the solution:**

```
$str = '';

foreach($_POST['pos'] as $value) {
  $str = $str.$value;
}

// Connect to database
$opendb = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

$new_value = "UPDATE users SET regnr='" . $str . "' WHERE username='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username']) . "'";
mysql_query($new_value) or die(mysql_error());

// Close database
mysql_close($opendb);
```